# Transfer Data from tables that end with _Log into a another DB and only leaving 1 week of data in the main DB?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

**Task:** Transfer data from all the tables(50 tables) that end with _log into a logdb and only leave 1 week of data in the main db.

edit: All log data is being populated in Production db and stored in tables that end with _LOG, I Need to move all data from those tables into logdb ,
logdb has all identical tables with some data in it already, I Just need to transfer/Add data weekly from Production to logdb and Clean out production tabls so they arent that heavy with million of records.

The way I thinking to do is

1.Get all the table that end with _Log

```
--Using SSIS Execute SQL Task
--SQL Statement  - > (SELECT name FROM SYS.tables WHERE name LIKE ('%_genLog'))
```

2. I Would run a  ForEachLoop Container

   --> DataFlow Task
     -->OLE DB source
     -->Conditional split
     -->OLE DB Destination (LogDb)
     --> FlatFile(data back into main db)

3/4. Truncate the table in the main data base, and put back data that is 1 week old.

I have never worked with variables so I am lost how to do this dynamically for each table, I Did for a single table at a time, but Im looking for a way to avoid 150 packages to move data on weekly bases.

I have attached the model of what I think it would look like, 
But I cant figure out how to do it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Forgot to mention that the logdb database already has those tables created in it, I just have to add new data into those tables, and keep 1 week of data in the main DB.
all _LOg tables are used to track changes that happened to the production table.

basically we have a product table and product_LOG table
So if someone removes anything or add/ changes in Product table, the whole action will be log into Product_LOG table.

These tables are very huge in size million of records, so I have to come up with a way to move all those changes into Logdb database and only keep 1 week of data in main database.

Comment: Are you loading in all the data into a single, log, table and then copying it into a main table and then truncating the main table? Are the tables to be truncated the same every time this is run. What are all tables used for?

Comment: All the tables are used to keep the track of the changes in each specific table, So each table has a different columns,
So the way I need to do it is take one table at a time load that table into a another db which has a table like in it already, just need to add new data.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with a SQL Task that will truncate all the tables.

Then you need to add a foreach container and in it load all the logs into a raw file destination using a dataflow task. In the dataflow task add a Conditional Split task to split the data into one week path (main table ) or log table.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to truncate all tables first, I need data in both tables, Whatever  data I have in logdb I need to add more to it from production db and at the end of the month I would make a backup of the logdb and Then Truncate the whole db, and then repeat, Basically thats the Idea. Just need a way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but truncate is kind of dangerous as if the copy was not successful you lose data.

Also what about prior data that is still in the backup.  Copy the whole table each week is not efficient.

Your diagrams do not seem to address new data.

I would write a tsql statement to do this.

Comment: The package would run overnight, 
What would be an efficient way to move data from large tables weekly from one db to a log database?
If I use select * from ..._LOG that wouldnt be so efficent because tables have million of records.

Comment: For that answer you would need to define prior data. Your diagrams are not consistent.  Answer is only as good as the question.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not quite sure what you mean, I have added more details to my question. Hope that would help to understand the task more.Thanks

Comment: How would we know the data is 1 week old?  I give up.  Good luck

Comment: with a Conditional split, every table has a DataAdded Column
So in Condtional Split I would have , 
DataAdded > DateAdd("dd",-7,Getdate()) --Data that is 7 days or less Old

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the Problem with my statement, If you can point me in the right direction I'll be more than happy to fix it. 
Thanks

Comment: You can lead a horse to water but you cant make them drink.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for trying.